# Can't completely remove chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, mac, google-chrome-extensions

Every time I add new user in Chrome (Mac OS), these two extensions get automatically added:

1. Domain Error Assistant 62u
2. eBay Shopping Assistant

[image: Chrome Extensions]

I have to remove them from each new user I add. I checked extensions from Safari, but it is not installed there:

[image: Safari Extensions]

They do not show in applications folder. I ran Malwarebytes in Mac and it removed two programs, supposedly these two. But after the removal I added a person in Chrome to check, and still these extensions got added. I tried this multiple times, and every time Malwarebytes detects two malware items, and removes them, but they still persist.

It is not a problem with sync, because I am adding new users to Chrome.

I want to remove them completely from my Mac (Sierra 10.12.2). How can I do it?